# Is this dry well sturdy enough to walk over?

Tags: drainage

I am planning to install a [dry well sold in HomeDepot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-24-in-Plastic-Storm-Water-Leaching-System-FWAS24/100377387) in my backyard. I am wondering if this dry well would be sturdy enough to walk over. If anybody has installed this product, could you share the experience?

Comment: I read this as *drywall*, instead of *dry well*! Was about to answer "**NO WAY!**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If installed [per instructions](http://www.ndspro.com/images/stories/pdfs/drainage/flowell_retail_install_guide.pdf) (buried a minimum of 8") walking on it should be fine. There is also an illustration of adding a vertical pipe in the middle to increase loading (probably a good idea with many of the heavier riding mowers.)